# ServiceStack multiple values in a single routing element

Tags: servicestack

Suppose I have following DTO classes

```
public class SumRequest : IReturn<SumResponce>
{
    public int First { get; set; }

    public int Second { get; set; }
}

public class SumResponce
{
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

It is possible to set routing strategy to [Route("/sum/{First}/{Second}", "GET")], and it will work.

But what about something like 
[Route("/sum/{First}+{Second}", "GET")] 
or 
[Route("/sum/{First}plus{Second}", "GET")]

Why it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack variable `{Path}` components must be separated by either `/` or `.` - so you will be able to use `.` for your variable separators, e.g:

```
[Route("/sum/{First}.{Second}")]
public class Sum : IReturn<SumResponce>
{
    public int First { get; set; }

    public int Second { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can then call with:

```
/sum/1st.2nd
```

For more info about ServiceStack's routing checkout the [Routing docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing).

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple routes for the same DTO. For example:

```
[Route("/sum/{First}.+.{Second}", "GET")]
[Route("/sum/{First}.plus.{Second}", "GET")]
public class SumRequest : IReturn<SumResponce>
{
    public int First { get; set; }

    public int Second { get; set; }
}

public class SumResponce
{
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

It looks like ServiceStack {Path} operators need to be separated by . or / chars (thank you Mythz).

Moreover, if you are using IIS, in order to use the plus sign (+) you need to allow double escaping for requests.

Comment: It is strange but browser says: 
RequestBindingException  

Unable to bind requestStack 

ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath)
ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)
when I try http://localhost:8088/sum/1+2